# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Iterator already obtained

Tags: java, java-8

I modified this code to do several tasks in one directory:

```
public class HDDSerialNumber
{

    public void getHDDSerialNumber() throws IOException
    {
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/sys/block"), "sd*"))
        {
            // Get HDD Model
            StreamSupport.stream(ds.spliterator(), false)
                .map(p -> p.resolve("device/model")).flatMap(wrap(Files::lines))
                .forEach(System.out::println);

            // Get HDD Vendor
            StreamSupport.stream(ds.spliterator(), false)
                .map(p -> p.resolve("device/vendor")).flatMap(wrap(Files::lines))
                .forEach(System.out::println);

            // Get HDD Vendor
            StreamSupport.stream(ds.spliterator(), false)
                .map(p -> p.resolve("device/state")).flatMap(wrap(Files::lines))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }

    static <T, R> Function<T, R> wrap(IOFunction<T, R> f)
    {
        return t ->
        {
            try
            {
                return f.apply(t);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
            }
        };
    }

    interface IOFunction<T, R>
    {
        R apply(T in) throws IOException;
    }
}
```

But when I run the code I get this error stack:

```
run:
ST320LT012-9WS14
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Iterator already obtained
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixDirectoryStream.iterator(UnixDirectoryStream.java:118)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixSecureDirectoryStream.iterator(UnixSecureDirectoryStream.java:73)
    at java.lang.Iterable.spliterator(Iterable.java:101)
    at hardware.HDDSerialNumber.getHDDSerialNumber(HDDSerialNumber.java:25)
    at hardware.Hardware.main(Hardware.java:12)
Java Result: 1
```

Can you help me to fix the code, please? I suppose that Iterator already obtained must be used only once in this example but I don't have idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 8):

> While DirectoryStream extends Iterable, it is not a general-purpose Iterable as it supports only a single Iterator; invoking the iterator method to obtain a second or subsequent iterator throws IllegalStateException.

([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html))

The iterator of the `Iterable` returned by `Files.newDirectoryStream` (`DirectoryStream` implements `Iterable`) can only be used once. You can solve it by calling `Files.newDirectoryStream` separately for each of the 3 streams you are creating.

Instead of creating one `DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/sys/block"), "sd*");` and using it in all 3 `StreamSupport.stream` calls, create 3 `DirectoryStream<Path>`.

Example :

```
public void getHDDSerialNumber() throws IOException
{
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/sys/block"), "sd*"))
    {
        // Get HDD Model
        StreamSupport.stream(ds.spliterator(), false)
            .map(p -> p.resolve("device/model")).flatMap(wrap(Files::lines))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/sys/block"), "sd*"))
    {
        // Get HDD Vendor
        StreamSupport.stream(ds.spliterator(), false)
            .map(p -> p.resolve("device/vendor")).flatMap(wrap(Files::lines))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/sys/block"), "sd*"))
    {
        // Get HDD State
        StreamSupport.stream(ds.spliterator(), false)
            .map(p -> p.resolve("device/state")).flatMap(wrap(Files::lines))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

EDIT :

If you want to handle the case of a file that doesn't exist without interrupting the program execution, catch the exception thrown in that case.

For example :

```
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/sys/block"), "sd*"))
    {
        // Get HDD State
        StreamSupport.stream(ds.spliterator(), false)
            .map(p -> p.resolve("device/state"))
            .flatMap(wrap(path - > try {
                                     return Files.lines(path);
                                   } catch (IOException ioEx) {
                                     return Stream.empty();
                                   }))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

This would catch the exception and return an empty Stream.

Comment: Very good! Can I ask additional question? If file is not found I get java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException How I can just skip the file without interrupting the program execution?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I believe you can wrap the call the causes the exception with a try block and catch the exception. I'm not sure where the exception is thrown. I'm assuming either in `map` of `flatMap`. For example, if it's thrown in `map`, do `.map(p -> try {p.resolve("..");}catch(NoSuchFileException ex){})`.